# UltraVNC hangs when entering user credentials

Tags: windows-7, osx-lion, ultravnc

I have a windows 7 system on which I have installed UltraVNC

I use it to connect to my Apple Lion X.  It works most of the time, but sometimes when I choose my username it hangs, meaning that I can't type anything else, sometimes it lets me type a few characters of my password and then it hangs.

To resolve this I have to restart the Mac; after restart it will work for a few times, and then the same thing happens again.

What can I do about this?